# ¿Cómo guardar un atributo de otra tabla en un formulario solo cuando se necesite crear uno nuevo?

Tags: php, cakephp

La situación es la siguiente: tengo dos tablas llamadas "Marcas" y "Modelos". Modelos tiene una llave foranea hacia Marcas llamada id_marca. Lo que pretendo es que al insertar un nuevo modelo, en el formulario aparezca id_marca con un dropdown y que salgan todas las marcas existentes y que además me dé la opción para agregar una nueva marca en caso de que esta no exista, haciendo que se agregue esta nueva marca en la tabla Marcas.

Esto haría que algunas veces se tenga que guardar un dato en la tabla Marcas y algunas veces no, esto desde el formulario de insertar modelo. Estuve buscando soluciones pero solo encontré para agregar siempre a ambas tablas. Por el momento lo tengo solo cargando las marcas existentes:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
<?php echo $this->Form->control('id_marca', array('options' => $marcas,'label'=>'Marca', 'class' => 'form-control')); ?>
```

**Editado**: este es el código de la parte de "agregar" del controlador de modelos

```
  public function add()
{
    $modelo = $this->Modelos->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $random = uniqid();
        $modelo->id = $random;
        $modelo = $this->Modelos->patchEntity($modelo, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Modelos->save($modelo)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('El modelo fue guardado exitosamente.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('El modelo no se pudo guardar, por favor intente nuevamente.'));
    }

    $marcas = $this->Modelos->Marcas->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $tipos = $this->Modelos->Tipos->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('modelo', 'marcas', 'tipos'));
}
```

Creo que solo esto ocupas, el resto es el consultar, modificar, eliminar e index.

Comment: Lo que yo quiero es tener la opción de elegir de entre las marcas existentes en un dropdown talvez , y además si no existiera la marca tener la posibilidad de digitarla y guardarla de una vez. Poder elegir entre ambas opciones. No sé si quedó más claro?

Comment: Una nada mas por el momento

Comment: Estoy utilizando la versión 3.5

Comment: Listo ya lo agregué, por el momento tengo el agregar simple de un modelo y que me muestre todas las marcas existentes. Lo que faltaría es que me permita elegir en un campo si quisiera crear una nueva marca y ver cómo es la lógica del formulario para dependiendo del caso hacer submit de este campo o del item elegido del dropdown.